# Who is referred to by "they" in this reply?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, yes-prime-minister

In *Yes, Prime Minister* Series 2 Episode 7, Prime Minister Hacker referred to a math problem:

> If it costs 5 billion pounds a year to maintain Britain’s nuclear defences and 75 pounds a year to feed a starving African child. How many children could be saved from starvation if the Minister of Defence abandoned nuclear weapons.

Sir Humphrey gave an answer:

> None. ***They***’d spend it all on conventional weapons.

I once thought the *They* here referred to the African people; but now I’m not sure.

Could it refer to the Ministry of Defence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could it refer to the Ministry of Defence?

## Definitely.

The question is what would the MOD do with their budget for nuclear weapons if those weapons were abandoned.

The MOD would spend it on alternative weapons instead.

In *Yes, Prime Minister* there is a general premise that budgets must be spent *and*, ideally for them, increased every year.

Budgets = Power